# How do I interrupt the thread I am currently running?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

My Google skills seem to have failed me, so apologies if this is a simple question.

I simply want to interrupt ("kill" it I guess) the thread which I am currently running.

My class implements Runnable, and inside the run() method I want the thread to interrupt if a certain condition is met.

Cheers! :)

Comment: Just exit your run method: `return;`

Comment: And, if interrupting from deeper down, just `throw net RuntimeException()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other option depending on the context.  Thread.interrupt will likely be better, but this one might be useful too by just introducing a cancel boolean inside your class.

```
public class MyLongRunningTask implements Runnable
{
   private volatile boolean cancelled;

   public void run() {
      while (!cancelled) {
         System.out.println("Do something...");
      }
   }

   public void setCancelled(boolean cancelled) {
      this.cancelled = cancelled;
   }
}
```

Comment: `cancelled` should be `volatile` to prevent caching its value.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Quote OP: "**inside the run() method** I want the thread to interrupt".

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I see your point now.  I think the easiest way then would be to just exit the run method either by setting cancelled to true or just using a simple return statement.

Comment: Yes, this is in fact a very simple problem, no fancy stuff needed.

Comment: Oh, so the thread will simply stop if the run method no longer runs?
 
And using t.join in my separate main thread will work if run() simply stops, ergo I never have to interrupt?

Answer (score -1):

You have two choices:

`return;`

and most correct and recommended

`Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`